# JAVA custom MessagePanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create panel with customized text in it but this is what it shows :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Vf76y5w.png]

Also tried to place text instead of *points*  but it has the same effect. This is my code :

```
public class Combo extends JPanel {
    static int points = 1000;
        public Combo(){
            paintPoints p = new paintPoints();
            p.setFont(new Font("Brush Script Std",Font.PLAIN,72));
            add(p);

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new paintPoints());  //edit
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



    }

    class paintPoints extends JPanel{
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

                super.paintComponent(g);
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                int StringWidth = fm.stringWidth(String.valueOf(points));
                int StringAscent = fm.getAscent();
                int xCoordinates = getWidth()/2 - StringWidth/2;
                int yCoordinates = getHeight()/2 + StringAscent/2;
                g.setColor(new Color(128,0,0));
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(points), xCoordinates, yCoordinates);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you might directly add your ***paintPoints*** panel and then set the font, you do not need the use of the ***Combo*** JPanel. I copied your ***paintPoints*** code and worked perfectly for me.

And please note that you shall use an upper case letter to name your java class.

EDIT: You also need to call the 
         `frame.setVisible(true);`     method after you set the frame's size otherwise you won't see your panel unless you explicitly set a new panel size.
In fact calling `setVisible(true);` before setting the size of the frame will initate all of its component to a size of 0 width and 0 height.

Comment: how can i add it directly ? Check my edit. I get enclosing error when i do this .

Comment: Just use a JLabel with the custom Font. A JLabel allows you to control the alignment of the text as well so it is center in the space available to the label.

Comment: Can I set the font and color of a jlabel ?

Comment: @zaa Yes you can `label.setFont(font);` and `label.setForeground(Color);` for every JComponent